# How to break for loop from inside of its try catch block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, for-loop, try-except

I'm trying to find a way to get out of this for loop **if the code block inside the try except block (inside the for loop) is succesfully executed**, and not calling the exception.

Here's the code which doesn't work for me :

```
attempts = ['I15', 'J15']
for attempt in attempts:
    try:
        avar = afunc(attempt)
        break
    except KeyError:
        pass
        if attempt == attempts[-1]:
            raise KeyError
```

Because it's still calling the `J15` item inside the attempts list after the `I15` is succesfully executed

The code here :

```
    except KeyError:
        pass
        if attempt == attempts[-1]:
            raise KeyError
```

Is used to throw the actual exception if the code already tried the whole `attempt` in `attempts`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `for … else` concept: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

```
attempts = ['I15', 'J15']
for attempt in attempts:
    try:
        avar = afunc(attempt)
    except KeyError:
        # error, let's try another item from attempts
        continue
    else:
        # success, let's get out of the loop
        break
else:
    # this happens at the end of the loop if there is no break
    raise KeyError
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cleanest way will be to `continue` inside the `except` block, and `break`ing just after it. In this case you don't even have to use `avar` (unless I misunderstood the question).

```
attempts = ['I15', 'J15']
for attempt in attempts:
    try:
        afunc(attempt)
    except KeyError:
        continue
    break
```

If you do need `avar` for a later usage:

```
attempts = ['I15', 'J15']
for attempt in attempts:
    try:
        avar = afunc(attempt)
    except KeyError:
        continue
    break
print(avar) # avar is a available here, as long as at least one attempt was successful
```

Comment: uhm, yes i still need avar, since the try except block needs to generate a value for a variable

Comment: @DyaksaHanindito if both attempts are not successful, then there is no `avar` defined at the end.